# Card game: How much will you pay to gamble?

Tags: probability, game-theory, card-games

You turn over the cards 2 at a time, if they are both red, you keep the cards, if they are both black I keep the cards. If one is red and the other is black then neither you nor I get a card. If you have more cards then I you win $100 otherwise you win nothing. What is the maximum amount you are willing to pay to play this game?

Comment: How big is the deck?

Comment: 52 cards - a regular deck

Comment: OK, maybe you should edit that information into the question. But maybe one way to approach the problem is to solve it first for a 2-card deck, then 4-card, 6-card, looking for a pattern or a recursion.

Comment: okk. Thanks! Can you give me an example? My math skills are rather poor..

Comment: Actually, the question I should have asked was, how many red cards in the deck, and how many black? If the numbers are the same, then for each time there are 2 red cards turned over, there must be a time when two black cards are turned over, so you never win, and shouldn't pay anything.

Comment: ok. They are equal. There are also cases when a red and a black card turn up-which would be about 50% right?

Comment: Hi Andre-which 14numbers? Can you please explain how to solve

Comment: I was being silly, a simple path to the answer was given by Gerry Myerson.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Can you please provide a detailed answer? what about the times when a red/black combination pops up-will take be 50% probability

Comment: @Random: The number of red/black pairs are irrelevant, since they just get thrown away without affecting the "score". All that matters is the number of all-red pairs and the number of all-black pairs.

Comment: And if you chuck away the red/black pairs, there must be an equal number of red pairs and black pairs remaining. Probability actually has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Got it...Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in my comment, I wouldn't pay anything to play this game, since I can't win.

Assuming that there are exactly as many red as black cards in the deck (for example, if it's an ordinary 52-card deck), then at the end of the game, I will have turned over two red cards exactly as often as I will have turned over two black cards. Thus, I will have exactly as many cards as you, and I won't win any money. So, I shouldn't pay any money to play.

Comment: Okay, so Gerry Myerson won't pay anything. Who will? >:) (I guess that isn't a math question anymore though.)